# Lista vacia cuando intento subir multiples fotos en angular + spring

Tags: spring-boot, angular8, multipart

Estoy intentando subir varias imagenes, en vez de una sola. Pero siempre me llega la lista vacia al backend, aunque en la parte de frontend lo añade bien en el formdata. Si hago la prueba desde postman, entonces la lista si llega informada.

He probado distintas soluciones, pero no hay manera de que funcione.
Mi codigo es:

**Controlador Java**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/mycars")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestPart(value = "archivos") List<MultipartFile> archivos,
@RequestPart("car") String car, BindingResult result )
```

**Servicio Angular**

```
create(car : Mycar, archivos: Array<File>) : Observable<HttpEvent<{}>>{
 
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("car", JSON.stringify(car));
 
  for (var i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
      formData.append("archivos", archivos[i]);
   }
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.urlEndPoint}`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
}
```

He probado a añadirle distintas cabeceras, pero da igual lo que añada siempre llega la lista vacia.

Necesito ayuda.

Mil gracias.